# Problem with getting data properly from memory using RoCC interface

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog

I am using RoCC interface to communicate with Memory in chipyard.

The memory has the width of 64 bits, and I need to read the first 64 bits and put it in lower register and then read the next 64 bits and put in the upper register, then make my own packet of data by `packet <= {upper, lower};`

And repeat the process until I read all the required values from the memory.

The problem is when I request to LOAD data from memory, sometimes during the memory response valid signal there are two 64 bits and other times there is only one. Please see the picture attached below:

[image]

This is my code to get the upper and lower values:

```
reg [63:0] upper, lower;
reg [127:0] packet;
reg [1:0] counter;

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
        lower <= 64'd0;
        upper <= 64'd0;
        counter <= 2'd0;
        packet <= 128'd0;
    end else begin
        if (mem_resp_valid) begin
            if (counter == 2'd0) begin
                lower <= mem_resp_data;
                counter <= counter + 2'd1;
            end else begin
                upper <= mem_resp_data;
                counter <= 2'd0;
            end
        end
        packet <= {upper, lower};

    end
end
```

I use `packet` in the other part of the design.

The lower values are correct, but I am not getting the right values for the upper after the fourth `mem_resp_valid` where there is only one data valid instead of two.

The expected values for the lower and upper are as follows:

```
lower1 = 1
upper1 = 2

lower2 = 3
upper2 = 4

lower3 = 5
upper3 = 6   // but gets the same value of lower3 instead
```

**EDIT** the data values stored in memory are organized like:

[image]

And this how I make LOAD requests from the Memory:

```
if(mem_req_ready) begin
    mem_req_valid <= 1'b1;
    mem_req_cmd <= 5'd0;       // zero means LOAD. one means STORE
    mem_req_size <= 2'h3;      // size 3 means, load 2^3 bytes on each request, here i need 64 bits hence 3
    mem_req_tag <= mem_req_tag + 8'h1;

    mem_req_signed <= 1'b1;
    mem_req_mask <= 8'h11;  // this is to set how many of the bytes for store request are valid

    if (mem_req_addr == 40'd0) 
      mem_req_addr  <= src_addr; // start fetching from source address/ initial address
    else begin
      mem_req_addr <= mem_req_addr + 40'h8;       
    end
  end
```

So I need to put 1, 3, 5, ... in the lower and 2, 4, 6, ... in the upper. But I don't know why for some values, the mem_resp_valid is 2 cycles and for others is one cycle.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. During the fourth `mem_resp_valid` pulse, it is clear that `mem_resp_data` has the same value for both clock cycles, so why wouldn't you expect that both `lower` and `upper` end up with that same value? The `*7e` data becomes the `lower` value for the following packet.

Comment: @DaveTweed I just updated my post . please let me know if you need more info

Comment: OK, the new timing diagram adds some key information. But you can't keep feeding us tiny tidbits of code. If you want serious help with this, you need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as explain exactly what the difference is between what you expect to happen and what actually happens. I'm assuming (because you haven't said) that this is an AXI memory interface, or something very similar. In this kind of interface, you're making a new request on every clock cycle for which both `mem_req_ready` and `mem_req_valid` are true.

Comment: ...  On the second time that `mem_req_ready` goes high, you're providing the same address (...4260) for both clock cycles, and that's why the memory returns the same word (...0005) twice in its response.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll try to share an MCVE. Yes, RoCC is similar to AXI but not the same. This is the interface between the accelerator and L1 cache in Rocket-chip. I am using chipyard environment and made some changes to chisel/scala code to make this to work. So I hope my MCVE will be enough for my problem.

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard and https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip? It would have saved a lot of time to include links in your original question.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that. Maybe I will post another question with all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data value of `6` on `mem_resp_data` is only held for one cycle, and it is the cycle when `count` is 0.  This means that `lower` samples the `6` data in that cycle.  During that cycle, `upper` does not sample `mem_resp_data`, so it retains its previous value `5`.  The Verilog simulation is behaving as expected.

If you want `upper` to sample the `*6` data in the next cycle (when `count` is 1), you need to extend the `mem_resp_data` into the next cycle.